# EJB web service endpoint URLs changed when upgraded from Glassfish 3.0 to Glassfish 3.1.2

Tags: ejb, glassfish-3

The development team I'm currently working with is planning to upgrade the Glassfish server application running on the server from version 3.0 (Sun Glassfish) to version 3.1.2 (Oracle Glassfish), and encountered an issue where the EJB web service endpoint URLs changed from:

```
http://serverip:port/PROJECT_NAME/primeRequestTTService
```

To:

```
http://serverip:port/primeRequestTTService/primeRequestTT
```

Upon days of Googling, I found out that the latter URL is currently the standard construction of EJB endpoint while since I found nothing on the former, I assume it was Sun Glassfish non-standard method of constructing the endpoint URLs.

The code excerpt as below:

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(serviceName = "primeRequestTTService", portName = "primeRequestTTSoap", wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/primeRequestTT/primeListTT.wsdl")
@Stateless
public class primeRequestTT {
    @EJB
```

I tried to set PROJECT_NAME as the `serviceName` attribute but end up with `http://serverip:port/PROJECT_NAME/primeRequestTT` instead.

**The question:**
Other than modifying all the EJB web service class names to have "Service" prefixes, how do I modify this web service application project to maintain the previous endpoint construction while I upgrade the Glassfish to version 3.1.2? I'm looking for "configuration file" type of solution. I already tried `glassfish-web.xml` and it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Lukman,

You have to include 'name' parameter into your @WebService annotation:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "primeRequestTTService", portName = "primeRequestTTSoap", name= "primeRequestTT")
```

So, your will end up as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/primeRequestTTService/primeRequestTT
```

Comment: So, to get URL = http://serverip:port/PROJECT_NAME/primeRequestTTService as in the question, I must set serviceName = "PROJECT_NAME" and name = "primeRequestTTService"? Will try now ..

Comment: OK it works. Thanks! But is there a solution that doesn't require editing the class annotation in each file? Something like an XML config file ..